# 1) Iterate Models(Types) in Ember Data Store? 2) Add Ember Models(Types) to Ember Data Store at run time?

Tags: loops, types, runtime, ember-data

I am newbie to Ember, but I'd like to do the two jobs with Ember Data:

1) Iterate through all types (sub-classes of  DS.Model) in my Ember Data store. Ember-Data seems not to provide this function.

Not sure if Ember.Observable can observe the changes of Ember Data store, which may provide the model collection in the store.

2) Instead of coding each Ember Data Model/Route/Controller/View in the project, I'd like to be able to create Ember Data Models or Types at run time, e.g. User can enters a model Fixtures in a text area, like:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
```

Then, my web application should add this fruits model into Ember Data store for future use. Any idea on how to do it?